# Object A is a member of B and the Object B is a member of A

Tags: c++, oop

I have a c++ where in classes A and B each one has a member of the other class. How can I solve this ?

```
class A {
     B memberY;
}


class B {
     A memberX;
}
```

Comment: Excluding poor OOA&D, when classes are interdependent like this, it usually means that a helper-class exists that implement the dependencies. E.g.: team contains member, member contains team -> the helper-class could be team_member that is used by both team and member.

Answer (score 6):

You use pointers and forward declarations.

```
//A.h

class B; //forward declaration to class B

class A {
     B* memeberY;
}

header for class B:

//B.h

class A; //forward declaration to class B

class B {
     A* memeberX;
}
```

You can't do this with object instances, only with pointers, since an instance would require the compiler to know the full definition of the class.

Note that if memory management is assigned to the class, you should free the memory on the destructor. That means you should also override the `copy constructor` and `operator =` in your classes.

You can have one of the classes contain an object of the other class, but you have to include the other classes' header in the header. The other one would have to be solved with a forward declaration.

Comment: (on d-vote: undone - I read too quick & thought too slow) see my comment on the question for my approach (OO), where yours is C++.

Answer (score 3):

It isn't possible as you would like it. One of those classes has to be a pointer to the other one. You cannot have a recursive relationship of actual objects -- the size of the object would be infinite.

So you probably need something like this:

```
struct B;
struct A
{
  B * myB;
};
struct B
{
  A * myA;
};
```

Now, construction becomes a problem since they both need a reference to each other. That is why I can't provide you with a constructor, since I don't know how you will construct these objects.

You now also have a cleanup problem, since presumably one of these objects owns the other -- they both can't own each other. That excludes the use of `unique_ptr`. I would have used `smart_ptr`, but then you still have a memory link unless you have some function to break the circular reference.

But if you'd better indicate why you want to do this perhaps a more appropriate answer can be given.